# C++ comparing 2 strings

Tags: c++, string-matching

I have the following code:

```
int compare(string a,string b)
{
    int length=a.length();
    for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<b[i])
            return 1;
        if(a[i]>b[i])
            return 0;
    }
    ....
}
```

I'm interesting in the cases when length of string a is bigger than length of string b and string a starts with string b.

Example: 

string a="abcdefghi"

string b="abcde"

The function will return 0. I want to know if there is any chance for this function to return 1; in this conditions.

Comment: Written as it is, no. You should also consider `b.length` in the `for` loop. If you find yourself in the condition where one of the strings is over and you still have characters on the other, you know you have to return non-zero.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873209/implementation-of-strcmp/34873406)'s a bunch of implementations in C which you can take inspiration from.

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior, so anything can happen.  `b[i]` is undefined when `i >= b.length()`

Comment: Are you writing your compare function for the sake of it or do you just need to compare two strings? If it's latter case you just can write `a < b`.

Comment: I have a program that has a bug and I'm trying to find it (don't know the cases in which doesn't work and can't find a test where the program doesn't work but I know for sure that it has a bug) so I found this sequence of code and if this function can return 1 in this conditions that means this is one of the bugs.

Comment: I wonder why you return 0 if a[i]>b[i] - and what about a[i]==b[i]?

Comment: I didn't put the whole function and i just put random numbers on return because is not relevant to the question.I just wanted to know if it's possible to return 1 in this conditions. Here is the whole function https://pastebin.com/vduLJenZ and as you can see length will always have the length of a(pathPrev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total two scenarios are possible:-

1. if we have the length of `b > 0` , then we have to make sure that
   `a[i] ASCI`I value must be less than `b[i]` ASCII value..

   ```
   string a="abcdefghi"
   string b="abcde"
   ```
2. In your example when we reach at index `5`, the result would be
   undefined, means `b[5]` might contain garbage value whose *ASCII*
   value is greater than `a[i`]. or the result might be vise-versa.

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for, so in some cases in this conditions is possible for the function to return 1, thanks you. Also thanks to @Sid S for pointing out the same thing.